# Express JS 4 and html5Mode redirect not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to implement html5mode(true) for my angular app on my Node/Express server.

I'm getting the dreaded "cannot /GET" error when I try to reload.

The fix that I see being implemented for this on the server is by adding a catch all get request in the express app.js.

I've done that, but It's not working for me.

Here is my code where I add the catch all at the bottom, but when I reload, I get the following message: Error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/express4/testproj/server/client/app/index.html' at Error (native)"

That's clearly not what I'm calling below.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());    

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/sendmail', require('./routes/sendmail'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app/custom')));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.all('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

module.exports = app;
```

My angular module has the standard...

```
'use strict';


angular
    .module('clientApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ui.router',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'xeditable'
    ])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            });

    }])
```

Comment: Please also add sample angular call

Comment: Added. Pretty standard on the angular side. Base ref is also included on index just in case.

Comment: I haven't done this yet for my app, but it's on my to-do list. Check out this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode