# Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode and java spring in serverside

Tags: angularjs, servlets, angular-ui-router

Here is my **web.xml** file

```
<display-name>PhysicalInventory</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('inventoryApp', [
    //Third-Party modules
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.pagination'
  ])
  .config(function ($urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
alert("ii");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');


    $stateProvider
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashbord.jsp',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }).run(function ($rootScope, $state){
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
 });
```

When I am running my aap its working finr for first time. but While reloading its showing HTTP Status 404 - /PhysicalInventory/dashboard.

Kindly anyone help me out......

Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be you have problem in your backend

Comment: what might be the problem @ojuskulkarni ...first time when i am running its comming to /dashboard route and working fine...but when i reload its getting 404 error...

Comment: You are getting 404 on same url path or path get changed whe you reload ?

Comment: same url http://localhost:8083/PhysicalInventory/dashboard

Comment: @ojuskulkarni the path get changed from /dashboard to /PhysicalInventory/dashboard when reloading

Comment: before it included # in url.. and was working fine in reloading the page...but when i used $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in app.js and in index.jsp page <base href="/PhysicalInventory/index.jsp"/> to remove #.... its working for # removal but occured another isue while reloading....

Comment: it's pretty frontend issue.. try to use absolute path instead of relative one

Comment: @SANDEEPPANDA That means you have some url issue. may be you are using same state for different url's, or share some code of related to `PhysicalInventory/dashboard`.

Comment: @ojuskulkarni in my browser when i put  "localhost:8083/PhysicalInventory/  "then it will automaticaly append dashboard and redirect to dashboard page...but after that when I reloading the same its showing the error like HTTP Status 404 - /PhysicalInventory/dashboard   here nowhere we are configured the PhysicalInventory/dashboard neither in web.xml nor in app.js.  So i think it may be server side problem ie. in web.xml. but if i am not removing # from url then how it is working fine??? I donot understand exactly....Please comment..

Comment: Actually after context path # seperate the url, means what ever you mention in state it shows url accordingly. if possible then share code so may be I ll help you. share the code related to url and `.state`.

Comment: **follow this steps** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode/39121394#39121394