# AngularJS component routing shows 404 on refresh or when manually entering url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using XAMPP Apache to run angular on localhost. When the server starts it goes into index.php, calls a component 
then from inside the app, it default links to Login with the path '/login' specified in the $routeConfig

```
.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.component('app', {
    templateUrl: 'component/app/app.html',
    $routeConfig: [
        {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: 'login'  , useAsDefault: true}
    ]
```

refresing localhost:8000/login returns 404 

I have tried adding

```
<base href="/" />
```

in the header and tried .htaccess but still does not work. Does anyone know any solutions to fixing 404 on refresh for angular component routing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode). Also answered here ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: You need to setup URL rewriting on the server. All requests need to be re-written to your index page so angular routing can then take over from there

Comment: thanks, both your answers were on point. Nevertheless I just didn't bother and just set html5Mode to false because the localhost is on apache but the server deployed is another. I couldn't find a general way to do it and the solutions were all direct to specific servers.