# refreshing a page in angular js causes url not found error

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a simple `AngularJS` project where the path of `index.html` is `ProjectName/index.html` and my other `html` files are at `projectName/templates/xxx.html` and my `script.js` path is same as `index.html`.My base refernece line is `<base href="/Projectname/">`  .But when I refreshed the page, I am getting page not found error.
Error comes when i reload Home page and students page.

Myindex.html code

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html ng-app="myModule">
       <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Insert title here</title>
       <base href="/routing/">
        <script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="script.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <table style="">
      <tr style="background-color: gray;">
        <th colspan="2" class="header"><h1>Header</h1></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftMenu" style="background-color: #cecece;"><a
            href="home">Home</a> <a href="courses">Courses</a> <a
            href="students">Students</a></td>
         <td class="mainContent" colspan="2"
             style="background-color: lightgray;"><ng-view></ng-view>                             </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: gray;">
        <td colspan="2" class="footer"><b>Website Footer</b></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My script.js

```
        var app = angular
    .module("myModule", [ "ngRoute" ])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/home", {
            templateUrl : "Templates/home.html",
            controller : "homeController"
        }).when("/courses", {
            templateUrl : "Templates/courses.html",
            controller : "coursesController"
        }).when("/students", {
            templateUrl : "Templates/students.html",
            controller : "studentsController"
        }).when("/students/:id", {
            templateUrl : "Templates/studentDetails.html",
            controller : "studentDetailsController"
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : "/home"
        })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })
    .controller("homeController", function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Home page";
    })
    .controller("coursesController", function($scope) {
        $scope.courses = [ "c#", "Android", "Java", "Html", "PHP" ];
    })
    .controller(
            "studentsController",
            function($scope, $http) {
                $http
                        .get(
                                "http://localhost/angulartest/services/api.php?list")
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $scope.students = response.data;
                        });
            })
    .controller(
            "studentDetailsController",
            function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
                $http(
                        {
                            url : "http://localhost/angulartest/services/api.php",
                            method : "get",
                            params : {
                                id : $routeParams.id
                            }
                        }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.student = response.data;
                    $scope.message = "student details";
                    console.log($scope.student);
                })
            });
```

Nd my other html files like home.html ,students.html are available in Templates folder in path Projectname/Templates/xxx.html

Comment: which page you refreshed? and which page you are in? pls add few more details in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

Answer (score 1):

The base href and the url you specified are different:  Projectname vs ProjectName capitalization is important on some systems

Also the urls need to be rewritten server side as when you refresh the page a new GET request is generated to the server which causes a 404 as the server isn't aware of the routes you've defined in Angular

Comment: can you explain me what is projectanme capitalization @Brian

Comment: The URL specified by `<base href="/Projectname/">` is different to the  `ProjectName/index.html` URL's are case sensitive so /ProjectName isn't the same as /Projectname as such specifying a base href of /Projectname/ when files are stored in /ProjectName/ may cause a 404.

Comment: i hav just givaen sample name as projectName .but i have given correct without any case differenec

Comment: Ah k no worries the example wasn't available to me when I posted my answer will take another look as soon as I get a chance

Comment: I've looked into it further - the problem is that when you refresh the page the URL has been updated via the history API but as the server knows nothing about this it can't serve it. You need to setup something server side to rewite the URL and serve your index.html for those particular angular routes. This question appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode

Comment: thank you brian .i have tried with rewrite rules and its working

Comment: No worries at all I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.