# $locationProvider in angular url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, angular-ui-router

Recently I have developed a website http://www.skduhariya.com, this is completely based on angularJS.  I'm using the concept of ui-router for routing between the static pages. Symbol(#) is being displayed in the URL like `skduhariya.com/#/blogs`

I tried using `$locationProvider` to remove Symbol(#) from the URL so URL becomes like `skduhariya.com/blogs`,

its working fine, But, when we refresh the browser is not working as expected. Its display 404-Page Not found.

code:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {      
    $stateProvider.state('public', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'src/public/public.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

can anyone help me out to fix this.

Comment: Can please add some code, so people can understand what happens ?

Comment: plz post your code .

Comment: What server are you running the app on? You need to route all requests to your index.html

Comment: [github.com](http://github.com)

Comment: You will have to find out if github hosting supports routing. Not sure if they do - https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408

Answer (score 0):

You may could watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

As he is already describing:

> **Server side** 
>   Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side,
>   basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
>   application (e.g. index.html)

:)