# 404 when refreshing angular routes

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already tried to put

```
<base href="/index.html"> and/or <base href="/">
```

I have configured my .htacess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index1.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

And this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# If the requested pattern is file and file doesn't exist, send 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

And I also knows that my mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
apache2ctl -M^C
> rewrite_module (shared)
```

This works for load the home, and clicking all links... but, if I open /login through click, it will open normally. But if I just reload it, or type in the url address the same address, it will not work, it gives me 404. Any ideas?

Ps. I am using ui-route `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` so the routes don't have #, the route IS /login, and this works.... in all the scenarios except the refresh one

Comment: Not a ReWriteRule master, but for the issue you are having you need to add a rule that will accept `/login` and redirect/rewrite to `/index.html#login` or similar according to your `angular router` setup..When you perform a page refresh the request hits the server, returning 404 for `login` does not exist as a server resource.. It's just a route in your angular app

Comment: But I can't do this for each route..... This is why I am using this: `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]` everything (login for example) should be redirect to index.... I am using ui-route with htmlMode true, so there's no "#" in the url

Comment: have you tried ui-serf

Comment: I never tried that, but I don't think it's the solution because since I am getting 404 (from apache, it's not even the defined 404 from angular), the problem is that apache is trying to find a "login" folder... so, I believe that something in the html code will not fix that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

Comment: I know there are several similar questions, but, since none of the solutions I have found worked for me, I tried to ask again... sorry

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was in the apache2.conf, I didn't know I had to `allowRewrite: All` not only in the `sites-available/default` but also in `apache2.conf`.
So, this worked for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^. index.html [NC,L]
```