# Angularjs refresh on HTML5 mode breaks the page styles

Tags: angularjs

I have an existing angularjs application (version 1.5.11). The requirement is to have pretty url's instead of the "#".
Based on the reading from SO sources, I have made the following changes:

- Enabled the html5mode

  ```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
  });
  ```
- Added base url

  ```
  <head>
     <base href="/">
     ...
  </head>
  ```
- Updated the nginx url re-write rules (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

The issues I have now is,

If the type the url say https://testing.something.com/#/media/55315, the page redirects properly and the updated url is https://testing.something.com/media/55315

However, If i try to refresh the page with url https://testing.something.com/media/55315, the page loads, but styles are all broken.

Why aren't nested urls working on refresh?

Any directions will be helpful.

Comment: Are you getting 404 error for `css` in console  ? What are the errors? Share screenshot

Comment: let me share the url https://testing.stohke.com/#/media/55315 (redirects properly) & https://testing.stohke.com/media/55315 (refresh is broken)

Comment: This might help. Please refer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570533/5409913

Comment: Probably using relative paths for link href