# After refresh AngularJS page in gulp server, showing error as cannot GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angularjs-ng-route

I have a gulp server with AngularJS 1.6 application.

I have an ng-router. I am trying to remove `#!` symbol from the url, so I have used ng-router. I have used `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and in index.html I have used `<base href="/">` at the top.

but when i refresh the page it is showing Cannot GET `/ui/index.html/`

I am using `gulp` server.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("apollo", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/ui/index.html/', {
      templateUrl: 'root.html',
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
    })

    .when('/ui/:appName/', {
      templateUrl: 'apps/' + localStorage.getItem('locationApp') + "/controllers/home/templates/home.template.html"
    })

    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/ui/index.html/'
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Apollo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="library/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="library/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="services/apollo-headerCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="services/AppCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="apollo">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to check router in BE, when `/ui/*`. You should return index.html in this case

Comment: ok, let me try this

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: You can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiVtu58xVJY)

Comment: @TanDuong, i checked this link, but do you now how to add .htacess file in gulp server as i am using gulp. i am not using tomacat or any other server

Comment: This is just example. You need to understand how it work. When you go to the link `/ui/` BE side didn't know which file need to return to FE side to show

Comment: The change is needed at server-side & not the client-side (gulp) code (url re-writing needed). Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode